# Access the radio-button from rails form in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am building a rails app. I would like to access the radio_button value in Java Script(in document.getElementById). Below is the code snippet from the form.html.erb.
Kindly let me know on how to access the same. I tried a lot of options. But nothing worked.

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= "Yet to start" %>
          <%= radio_button("section", "1", "Tag1", :checked => true) %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= "In Progress" %>
          <%= radio_button("section", "2", "Tag2") %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= "Completed" %>
          <%= radio_button("section", "3", "Tag3") %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Inspect the outputted HTML. Get the ID and use it in javascript

Option 2: Specify the ID manually, like: `<%= radio_button("development_activity", "progress", "Yet to start", :checked => true, :id => 'custom_id') %>`

Comment: @Prakadeessh, once rendered to the browser, remember it isn't Rails anymore. It's simply HTML. The rendered HTML becomes more important than the originating view.